# Is there a way to get the count of filtered options in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using `react-select` for multiple selection from a list of options.

**Required Behavior**

I'm keeping the input value even after the user selects an option by checking the `action` in `InputActionMeta`. I would like to clear the input once all options matching the current search input are selected. So I am looking for a way to get the number of available options that are filtered based on the search input.

I have not created a custom filter function as the default one works good enough for me. Is there any way to get the count of filtered options available without duplicating the filter method myself?

**Edit**

Code in question :

```
<Select 
    isMulti
    name='users'
    classNamePrefix='user-select'
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    backspaceRemovesValue={true}
    options={this.state.users}
    placeholder='Select Users...'
    onChange={(data) => {
        var searchTerm = this.state.searchTerm
        this.setState({selectedUsers:data, searchTerm:searchTerm})
    }}
    maxMenuHeight={200}
    onInputChange={(input,reason) => {
        if(reason.action==='input-change'||reason.action==='set-value')
            this.setState({searchTerm:input})
        else
            this.setState({searchTerm:''})

    }}
    isLoading={this.state.loading}
    inputValue={this.state.searchTerm}
/>
```

The users object :

```
users = [
    {value:'test1@test.com', label:'Test 1'},
    {value:'test2@test.com', label:'Test 2'},
    {value:'test3@test.com', label:'Test 3'},
    {value:'sample1@test.com', label:'Sample 1'},
    {value:'sample2@test.com', label:'Sample 2'},
    {value:'sample3@test.com', label:'Sample 3'},
]
```

**Sample Use Case**

I search for `sample` and 'Sample 1', 'Sample 2' and 'Sample 3' are now in filtered options. When I select the first 2 users, the 'sample' in the search box is still there. As soon as I select the last matching option, I want to clear the search term.

Comment: It'd be nice to have a reproducible link. For instance, to the https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: It would great if you add the exact code(that you describe) to the question for a better understanding of the problem

Comment: @marzzy I have added the code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a native `react-select` way to get the count of the filtered items. But you can make use of this trick to get the count. I hope react-select uses default `match` itself.

- You need to create a new state say `filterCount` to hold the count of filtered items.
- Rest is basic JS filtering

```js
onInputChange((input,reason) => {
        const currentInput = input.toLowerCase();
        const filteredItems = users.filter(user =>
          user.value.toLowerCase().match(currentInput)
        );
        if(reason.action==='input-change'||reason.action==='set-value') {
            this.setState({searchTerm: input, filterCount: filteredItems.length})
        } else {
            this.setState({searchTerm: '', filterCount: filteredItems.length})
        }
    }
  }
```